# When restart docker.io service,some docker containers don't start

Tags: logging, docker

When I restart the docker service by using the command:

#### service docker.io restart

Then I found some docker containers don't start normally and I also cannot found docker logs in /var/log.
could you help me?
Any suggestions appreciated.

such as :

#### I had 5 dockers at the beginning,

```
root@docker:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                                         NAMES
a841626ed335        ubuntu:14.04                /bin/bash              11 seconds ago       Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:809->80/tcp                                                           dreamy_elion         
b346335ed23b        ubuntu:14.04                /bin/bash              41 seconds ago       Up 40 seconds       0.0.0.0:889->80/tcp                                                           jolly_perlman        
da73442544c9        ubuntu:14.04                /bin/bash              About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:888->80/tcp                                                           silly_davinci        
bd6100c48b0a        shipyard/rethinkdb:latest   /usr/bin/rethinkdb -   17 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:49153->28015/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49154->29015/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49155->8080/tcp   shipyard-rethinkdb   
a258b27bb0b7        web-801:latest              /usr/sbin/apache2ctl   26 hours ago         Up About a minute   433/tcp, 0.0.0.0:802->80/tcp                                                  container-802
```

#### Then I restarted the service

```
root@docker:/home/ubuntu# service docker.io restart
docker.io stop/waiting
docker.io start/running, process 23046
```

#### After the restart,only 3 dockers left...

```
root@docker:/home/ubuntu# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                         NAMES
da73442544c9        ubuntu:14.04                /bin/bash              2 minutes ago       Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:888->80/tcp                                                           silly_davinci        
bd6100c48b0a        shipyard/rethinkdb:latest   /usr/bin/rethinkdb -   17 hours ago        Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:49153->28015/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49154->29015/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49155->8080/tcp   shipyard-rethinkdb   
a258b27bb0b7        web-801:latest              /usr/sbin/apache2ctl   26 hours ago        Up About a minute   433/tcp, 0.0.0.0:802->80/tcp                                                  container-802
```

Comment: Can you add some more infos, like a  `docker ps -a`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I had added the codes.

Comment: What do your 2 containers that disappear  do ? Can you post the code ? I

Comment: I just start the containers for a test,and do noting...and when I restart again , a new container disappear

Comment: Could you test some containers with your docker? and whether it happened probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Docker means doing Ctrl d for a container that was launched with a basic

`docker run -it ubuntu:latest bash`

So you have do start it again

If you do

`docker start a841626ed335`

and then

`docker attach a841626ed335`

You will be back in the first container.

If you run a daemonized container with

`docker run -d ubuntu:latest /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hi; sleep 3; done"`

It will restart automatically

I think

`docker ps -a`

would show

`exit 0`

for the 2 "missing" containers